# FIXED: Flask Validators and Redirect not working

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, flask-wtforms

Final Edit: I figured out that the issue was with my html and I had misspelled the beginning part of my register page . I had not written the form method correctly. Maybe this will help someone in the future if they have the same issue

```
<div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="">
```

---

Original Post:
I don't understand what is going on. I am using vscode and python 3.8

The DataRequired validator seems to be working fine but the Email, and EqualTo validators do not work. Vscode tells me there are these 3 problems with my forms.py code: unresolved import 'flask_wtf'; unresolved import 'wtforms'; unresolved import 'wtforms.validators'.
I find this odd since the DataRequired validator seems to be working just fine.

As well when the form is submitted the redirect does not work. The page just stays on the register page instead of redirecting to home.

Edit: Out of the validators the DataRequired validator is the only one that works and displays any message. Nothing happens for any of the other ones and it will allow a submit if the other ones are not completed(Length, Email, EqualTo)

forms.py:

```
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Your Name', 
                        validators=[ DataRequired(), Length(min=2,max=50) ])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email() ])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email() ])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

code for app

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = ['first task', 'second task']

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sercretKey'



@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
   return render_template('home.html', tasks=tasks)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account created for {form.name.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect( url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title = 'Register', form = form)

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title = 'Login', form = form)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: redirect is probably not working because the form is not validated.

what version of wftorms are you using?

Comment: These are all my version numbers:                                                                      
email-validator==1.1.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.3
idna==2.9
is-disposable-email==1.0.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pyodbc==4.0.30
Werkzeug==1.0.1
WTForms==2.3.1
wtforms-validators==1.0.0